# how to find all the .c files in a directory in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am new at MATLAB scripting and i am trying to sort out all the "c" files present in a directory(example.c, hello.c etc)

```
fileData = dir();                                             
m_file_idx = 1;     
filenames = {fileData.name};  
index = regexp(filenames,'\w*.c\w*','match') ;           
inFiles = filenames(~cellfun(@isempty,index))
i=1;
for idx = i : length(inFiles)                             
    c_files=inFiles{i}; 
    disp(c_files)
end
```

Am i using `regexp` correctly?

Comment: This question has been asked many times in various forms. Look through either my answered questions or POW's, we both just answered this yesterday...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: -

```
files=dir('*.c');
files_name={files(:).name} %as a 1xn cell
```

or

```
files_name=ls( '*.c') %as char matrix of n rows
```

n=no. of `.c` files in current working folder.

You can list all files from a specific folder like this:

```
dir('drive:\path_to_foder\*.c')
```